# Cannot share folders in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, shared-folders

When I try to share a folder on Windows Server 2008 R2, I get following error message

> **Windows File Sharing**
>
> Your system administrator has blocked you from running this program
>
> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or
>   because it has no enabled services associated with it.

[image: The error message from "Windows File Sharing"]

When I try to "Turn on file and printer sharing" in "Advanced sharing settings", I can press the "Save settings" button, but nothing happens. The window is not closed and no messages are showed. And if I close the window and reopen it, the changed settings have not been saved. 
[image: Advanced share settings]

The system is not connected to any domain and I'm administrator on the system.

Comment: I'm no networking guru, but...Public Profile ? Try Work Profile instead

Comment: The server is connected to a small standalone network and has no way to determine if it is a work or private network. So, Windows, set the network to the public by default. And there is no difference if I try to change the settings for Home or Work

Comment: It will, it's 'safest' & also the most locked down. If it's a home or work network, set it up as such; public is for just that, an untrusted open network, airport wifi, hotel, starbucks etc.

Comment: How do I make Windows to understand that it is a Work network?

Comment: Network & Sharing Centre. Click 'myNetwork' whatever it's called, change to Work Network.

Comment: I can not change the profile for some reason. And if I understand it right it does not matter. The only thin that the network profile change is the rules that are enabled in the firewall. I have manually enabled the firewall rules as needed, and it should not affect the fact that I can not enable file sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was due to the service "Application Information" was stopped. When I started it, it worked. :-)